# How to find out which network device is used to reach a given server

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, routing, traceroute

I have an overly complicated developer network setup with Ethernet, WLAN and VPN.

I can connect to certain server but I need to know which actual network device / router was used to make the connection. Depending on which network is used certain ports might be blocked and I have a suspicion the connection isn't going the way it should.

I use macOS but I'm fine terminal commands and have most of the gnu tools installed via MacPorts.

Comment: On Windows this is done with `tracert <destination name or IP>`. You'll be shown the address of every router along the route. Not sure what the equivalent is on MacOS.

Comment: Does macOS by chance have `route -4 get <ip>` / `route -6 get <ip>` (as in FreeBSD)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `route get 8.8.8.8` to find out which interface and gateway on the local computer is used according to the local routing rules. The `-4` and `-6` options as on BSD don't work, but the `-n` option for numerical output does work.

You can also use `traceroute 8.8.8.8` to find out the intermediate routers on the path (with the usual caveats when doing a traceroute).

**Edit**

`8.8.8.8` stands of course for the IP address you want to reach, it needn't be *literally* `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Or in the case of an internal routing issue, substitute `8.8.8.8` with the IP of your internal target host.

Comment: Thanks. `route get` gave me the output i needed and was able to fix the problem,

Comment: alternative to `traceroute` => `mtr`